# Nested struct returns empty from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, struct, datacontract

I need to return the following nested data from a WCF service as an `out` parameter of a call:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct PrinterInfo {
  public InkInfo Cyan;
  public InkInfo Magenta;
  public InkInfo Yellow;
  public InkInfo Black;
  public InkInfo LightCyan;
  public InkInfo LightMagenta;
  public int MaintenanceTankStatus;
  public int WasteInkTankStatus;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct InkInfo {
  public int InkStatus;
  public double Remaining;
};
```

Upon return from the service, all fields are empty. Normally, the obvious answer would be a data contract mismatch (something like different namespaces). But note that other calls in the same service, returning another, non-nested struct work flawlessly. Namespaces and everything similar are correct.

Things I tried:

- Adding and removing `DataContract`and `DataMember` attributes (both with namespace inherited from the assembly level and names set specifically, just to be sure). They are not required actually, the inferred contract would be just fine for me (the usual caveats don't apply, this is a fixed printer SDK and both sides of the service are in the same application, under my control).
- Adding `KnownType(typeof(InkInfo))`. No change.
- Adding `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]`. Being a struct, this results in an exception.
- Changing the structs into classes and trying all the above once more. No change.
- Logging and tracing the communication shows that the data *is* returned from the service, it's only the deserialization in the client that fails.

To recap: plain structs work perfectly. Only structs that contain other structs fail. Is there anything else I forgot to try?

**Update:** this is a fragment of the service, the other call returns the `BaseInfo` structure. And it does return it, no problems there.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.example.com/2017/06/printer-service", Name = "printer")]
public interface IPrinterService {
  [OperationContract]
  int GetBaseInfo(uint printerID, out BaseInfo out_BaseInfo);
  [OperationContract]
  int GetInkInfo(uint printerID, out PrinterInfo out_PrinterInfo);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class BaseInfo {
  public string PrinterSerial;
  public string Name;
  public string ModelName;
};
```

Normally, unless it turns out to be unavoidable, there is no explicit data contract, just the inferred one. Data contract namespace is provided at the assembly level (and it appears is the SOAP messages all right):

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://schemas.example.com/2017/06/printer-service", ClrNamespace = "MyApp.Printers")]
```

The service side happens to be written in C++/CLI but it looks almost the same:

```
int GetBaseInfo(unsigned int printerID, [Out] BaseInfo% out_BaseInfo) {
  ...
  Log::Debug(out_BaseInfo);
  return result;
}

int GetInkInfo(unsigned int printerID, [Out] PrinterInfo% out_PrinterInfo) {
  ...
  Log::Debug(out_PrinterInfo);
  return result;
}
```

Both `Log::Debug()` calls clearly show that the variables are populated before leaving the functions.

Comment: Can you show us the service code and data contract for one that is working vs one isn't, so we can compare?

Comment: Can you show us the code for GetBaseInfo and GetInkInfo?

Comment: Plain call to the similary named function of the channel: `return Channel.GetBaseInfo(printerID, out out_BaseInfo);` As I mentioned, logging and tracing reveals that the data *is* supplied by the service, there is no doubt about that. During testing, I also tried to simply replace all functions with ones that do nothing else but manually populate the out variable.

Comment: The structs are defined *exactly* the same way in the caller / client?

Comment: Yes, very exactly, no typo anywhere in a name

Comment: Oh, dear me. A difference between an `int` and a `long` (in C#, they are different but not in C++/CLI, they are the same there). Sorry for the false alarm... :-( Which one is better, to answer it myself or to delete the question? :-)

Comment: Answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, the computer was right. :-) There *was* a difference in some structs, a difference that was easy to miss: the difference between `int` and `long`. In the C# world, they are 32-bit and 64-bit, respectively, but in C++/CLI (to maintain compatibility) they are both 32-bit. I had a 'long' defined somewhere and it meant a difference...